# Using stream with fileupload manipulating the result somehow

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, image-processing, file-upload

Suddenly pictures that was showing before stopped showing on the page and checking the folder * discovered the image don't show when I click on them. Debugging my code I found the commented lines were causing it. Was the code below manipulating the stream in anyway?

```
public ActionResult UploadPhoto(UserPhotoUploadModel photoFileModel)
{
        HttpPostedFileBase photoFile = photoFileModel.PhotoFile;
    string uploadPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/users/photos");
    string autoFileName = String.Format("{0}_{1}", Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), filename);
    string fileDestName = Path.Combine(uploadPath, autoFileName);

    //Starting from here is where the issue lies
    Stream imgStream = photoFile.InputStream;
    using (imgStream)
    {
        Image img = Bitmap.FromStream(imgStream);
        int width = img.Width;
        int height = img.Height;

        if (width > 100 || height > 100)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("PhotoFile", "Photo dimension should be 100 by 100 or less");
            return View(photoFileModel);
        }
    }
    //the issue ends here

    photoFile.SaveAs(fileDestName);

    return RedirectToAction("Profile", new {id = loggedinUser.ProviderUserKey});
}
```

The saved files had the right image extension e.g. JPG. Am using the stream to determine the dimension of the uploaded image.

The commented portion is what is causing this issue. How can I do this with the Input stream still intact?

Thanks.

Comment: Without the commented areas, the images were saving perfectly, but when I add it, the images saved but blank/or not as real image, so it doesn't show in the browser. I think the `using` block wiped out the stream before `photoFile.SaveAs(fileDestName)` was called. I know this because moving `photoFile.SaveAs(fileDestName)` into the `using` works

Comment: How can I prevent the stream from being tampered with because obviously, rubbish/nothing is being saved to file - file exist in location but not a valid image file

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
 return View(photoFileModel);
```

When the code hits this line it exits out of the method. Therefore, this line is not executed:

```
photoFile.SaveAs(fileDestName);
```

Comment: No! the file get saved just empty or not valid image content

Comment: The empty or invalid file is created when you declare photoFile. Comment out return View(photoFileModel); and test it