# Alternative ways of finding if a string is an array

Tags: c#

I don't know if this question has been asked before. The way I know to do it am not convenient with it sometimes.

```
string[] exts = { "png", "jpg", "gif" };
if (exts.Contains(Path.GetExtension(filename)))
{
}
```

I would like to change the positions of the variables

```
if(Path.GetExtension(filename) is in exts)
{

}
```

Anyway to do it would be appreciated, LINQ, array function, etc

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking here.

Comment: @Oded I want the array to be on the right side.

Comment: I just feel there could be a better way. I've been doing like this for years, it doesn't feel right to me anymore - coding has evolved since then e.g. LINQ

Comment: LINQ implements a `Contains` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an extension method on `string` that takes a `string[]` and tests whether the string is in the array (using `Contains`) - then you would have `"aString".IsIn(myArray)`.

```
public static bool IsIn(this string toTest, string[] exts)
{
  return exts.Contains(toTest);
}


if(Path.GetExtension(filename).IsIn(exts))
{

}
```

Comment: Alright. I'm sorry to bother you, can you please look at my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761968/using-stream-with-fileupload-manipulating-the-result-somehow

Comment: @codingbiz - Looked at it and didn't answer because the commended area is too large. No errors/exception data was posted, so there is nothing to go on.

Comment: Without the commented areas, the images were saving perfectly, but when I add it, the images saved but blank/or not as real image, so it doesn't show in the browser. I think the `using` block wiped out the stream before `.SaveAs` was called. I know this because moving .SaveAs into the `using` works

Comment: `Stream imgStream = fileUpload.InputStream` I think it's by reference and the `using` block disposes it before being written to disk